# C: for loop with two nested for loops stops working after first cycle

Tags: c, for-loop

Can someone help me figure out why the for loop with the variable v doesn't execute after the first cycle?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int x[100],n,h,s,v,k,l;
    s=0;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    h=n;
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
        scanf("%d",&x[j]);
    for(v=0;v<n;v++)
    {
        for(k=0;k<n;k++)
            if(h%x[k]==0) x[k]=0;
        for(l=0;l<n;l++)
            if(x[l]==0) h--;
    }
    for(int m=0;m<n;m++)
        s=s+x[m];
    printf("%d",s);
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT** (this is a copy of the comment below!)

The input is 10 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 The expected result is 24, but the actual result is nothing, because the program just stops after the first cycle of v

Comment: Why don't you use a debugger to step through your code to find out for yourself? Or even basic debug print statements? There is alot more you can do before resorting to Stack Overflow. If you really need further help please provide the exact input, expected result and actual result.

Comment: The input is 10 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
The expected result is 24, but the actual result is nothing, because the program just stops after the first cycle of v.

Comment: `scanf("%d",&n);` - Check the return value from `scanf` and then print the value of `n`

Comment: Put braces around the contents of the for loops

Comment: What do you mean "just stops"? Is there any error msg? Your `printf` is unconditional. So unless the program crashed, something should print. So in what way are you determining that the program "just stops"?

Comment: Alright, so the debugger says there is an arithmetic exception on line 17, `if(h%x[k]==0) x[k]=0;` but i don't see where the problem is. I'm not dividing by zero or anything.

Comment: There is no error message, it just stops as if it ran normally.

Comment: Is `x[k]` 0 at that point by any chance?

Comment: Oh, it is. So I, in fact, am dividing by zero, I guess? But I don't know how to remedy that.

Comment: Your logic looks wrong. But you haven't described what your program is supposed to do so hard to give a precise comment. But the obvious problem is `x[k]=0` will set some of the entries to 0. Then when the outer loop runs again it will iterate the `x` array again and see those 0 values.

Comment: You don't need to do the division if `x[k]` is already zero.

Comment: The program is supposed to set all values in x that are factors of the total number of values in x to 0, and then repeat that while not counting the zeroes in the total, and do that until the values aren't factors of the total value, and then those final values are added up. So in this example 1, 2, 5 and 10 would get removed, and then the total number would be 6, so 3 and 6 would be removed, and then 7, 8 and 9 would be added to get 24. In the k loop I've added `if(x[k]==0) continue;` to skip all the 0 values.

Comment: That should fix the `k` loop. Now you just need to fix the `l` loop. Start `h` at 0, and increment `h` for any non-zero value in the array.

Comment: Yeah, I did that and now it works. Thanks for the help!

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) please follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  2) inset a (reasonable) space: inside parens, inside braces, inside brackets, after commas, after semicolons, around C operators.  3) always include the optional braces around the bodies of `if()`, `while()` `for()` statements

Comment: Thank you, I will do so from now on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

regarding:

```
if(h%x[k]==0) x[k]=0;
```

The modulo operator `%` is a 'divide by then return remainder' operation.

So when the contents of `x[k]` is zero a 'divide by zero' exception occurs and the program crashes.